# TypeScript - Element implicitly has an 'any' type [...] No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I'm struggling to get over an error on TS.

I define value (below in the code) according 2 interfaces that I created (WalletInformationsEdit and UserInformationsEdit)

The problem that I encounter is at the line right after the DB query, **value[field]** is underlined saying :

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'WalletInformationsEdit | UserInformationsEdit'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'WalletInformationsEdit | UserInformationsEdit'.
```

I have find 2 solutions to avoid this error message, but I am not ok because they make my code less protected:

1/ In TS config, if I take off "strict": true and "noImplicitAny": true -> working

2/ if I define value with "any" type, -> working

But both are not worth it, I suppose.

Do you have any recommandation to handle this case ?

Thanks in advance,

Paul

```
    public async update(value: WalletInformationsEdit | UserInformationsEdit): Promise<any> {

        try {

            // saving id before elem treatment
            const keepId = value.id
            delete value.id

            let filterFields = []
            for (let elem of Object.keys(value)) {
                filterFields.push(elem)
            }

            let i = 0;
            let updateList = [];
            for (const field of filterFields) {
              updateList.push(`"${field}" = $${++i}`);
            }

            const preparedQuery = {
              text: `UPDATE "${this.constructor.name.toLowerCase()}" SET
                    ${updateList.join()}
                  WHERE id = $${++i}
                  RETURNING *
              `,
              values: [...filterFields.map((field) => value[field]), keepId],
            };            

            const result = await db.query(preparedQuery);            

            return result.rows[0]

        } catch (error) {
            throw new Error(error.message)

        }


    }
```

WalletInformationsEdit and UserInformationsEdit interfaces

```
export interface UserInformationsEdit {
    id?: number,
    email?: string,
    password?: string,
    country?: string
}

export interface WalletInformationsEdit {
    id?: number,
    name?: string,
    is_default?: boolean,
}
```

Comment: Can you include the WalletInformationsEdit and UserInformationsEdit interfaces? See https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/index-signatures.

Comment: hey, I have added both interfaces above

Comment: You could try to implement generics to the function.

Comment: thanks you for your response, I have tried to understand how work index signature, and tried to get declarations from the interfaces like [id: string]: number ... but it does not work. Do you have an exemple to use it in my case ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally find the answer, to declare the index signature in my case, i had to declare it this way

```
export interface WalletInformationsEdit {
    [key: string]: number | string | boolean | undefined;
    id?: number,
    name?: string,
    is_default?: boolean

}
```

[key: string] -> index is read as a string

: number | string | boolean | undefined -> each type that composed my interface + undefined because properties are optional

thanks @DigitalDrifter for the link :-)

Comment: This helped me TREMENDOUSLY, I was calling object[key] and having to add //@ts-ignore every time.  Thank you!

Comment: Still a pleasure to help :D

Comment: There's one small issue. If you try getting a property that you never created for the type `this.generalProp` then typescript won't think this is an issue due to [key: string]: any; type. So I'm going to go with what @MattS was doing instead, way more useful in my case

Comment: Your answer to your own question is incredibly useful. Simple and straight to the point. Most people will just leave the question without coming back. Thanks for adding the answer!

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you're sure that the `field` is a key of `value`. So you can type it like this.

```
filterFields.map((field: keyof typeof value) => value[field])
```